# Local type definition for nested classes

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with nested classes in Typescript/Javascript to model what is possible in Java. This works pretty well. I can have static and non-static nested classes, derive from each other and so on. This is my test declaration:

```
class OuterClass {
    public static InnerClass2 = class InnerClass2 {
        public static InnerClass3 = class InnerClass3 {

        };

        public update(o: OuterClass): void {
            o.a = "b";
        }
    };

    public InnerClass1 = (($outer) => {
        class InnerClass1 {
            public static InnerClass3 = class InnerClass3 {

            };

            public update(): void {
                $outer.a = "b";
            }

        }

        return InnerClass1;
    })(this);

    public InnerClassDerived = (($outer) => {
        class InnerClass extends this.InnerClass1 {
            public constructor() {
                super();

                this.update();
            }

        }

        return InnerClass;
    })(this);

    private a = "a";

    private list: Array<InstanceType<typeof this.InnerClass1>> = [];

    public test(): void {
        const i = new this.InnerClass1();
        this.list.push(i);
        i.update();
    }
}
```

What bothers me, however, is this line:

```
private list: Array<InstanceType<typeof this.InnerClass1>> = [];
```

because of the long type description for the array. If `InnerClass1` were static I could define a type for it in a separate namespace, like for `InnerClass2`:

```
export namespace OuterClass {
    export type InnerClass2 = InstanceType<typeof OuterClass.InnerClass2>;
}
```

But that's not possible, as I need that `this` qualifier. Local type definitions in classes are not possible from what I know, so how could a possible solution look like to avoid the lengthy type in the array type declaration?

Ideally I would like to have this:

```
private list: this.InnerClass1[] = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close to the solution.  Instead of returning the class definition in the factory class properties, you should instead return a class expression.  Then, you can access the type of `InnerClass1` via `OuterClass["InnerClass1"]`

```
class OuterClass {
    public static InnerClass2 = class InnerClass2 {
        public static InnerClass3 = class InnerClass3 {

        };

        public update(o: OuterClass): void {
            o.a = "b";
        }
    };

    public InnerClass1 = (($outer) => {
      return class InnerClass1 {
        public static InnerClass3 = class InnerClass3 {

        };

        public update(): void {
            $outer.a = "b";
        }
      };
    })(this);

    public InnerClassDerived = (($outer) => {
        return class InnerClass extends this.InnerClass1 {
            public constructor() {
                super();

                this.update();
            }

        }
    })(this);

    private a = "a";

    private list: Array<OuterClass.classes.InnerClass1> = [];

    public test(): void {
        const i = new this.InnerClass1();
        this.list.push(i);
        i.update();
    }
}

export declare namespace OuterClass {
    export namespace classes {
        export type InnerClass1 = InstanceType<OuterClass["InnerClass1"]>;
        export type InnerClass2 = InstanceType<typeof OuterClass["InnerClass2"]>;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyCuAXApgJwMLitA3gWAChpjoAHeAIxAEthoJExFboBJAO3bU0ggCZoAXmihebTtyz9chEnLKUadBkxYcuGKQGYhIqeI08oO-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-kY9QkcQ5tIA+dEEqwg4KnY-YAKqvkNaGss3SkN+UUh7mk8LIvl0eDGVpNuI2A98hD2vLSu194ADNBxfc8Nz4a9b1ycVLCAA)

Comment: There's no difference between returning the class definitions or a class expression. And `Array<InstanceType<OuterClass["InnerClass1"]>>` still uses the `InstanceType`, which makes the entire expression ugly.

Comment: @MikeLischke There is a difference between returning the class definition vs class expression.  Classes are scoped to blocks and TypeScript disallows accessing classes from blocks beneath the current one because it considers those private.  Here's a minimal reproduction https://tsplay.dev/WKVzKm

Comment: @MikeLischke Also, you can now do the declaration merging using the solution I specified by accessing the class definition via interface access notation.

Comment: What I meant with my comment was that you don't need to change the inner class definitions. You can use the index signature on `OuterClass` with my unchanged code. But this isn't what I'm looking for. I want to simplify the list type declaration or at least allow a type alias somewhere.

Comment: @MikeLischke Ok, then you can declare the aliases using declaration merging.  Or, you can just make the types at the root or however so you prefer.  https://tsplay.dev/WJ4arN (scroll to bottom)

Comment: That's pretty cool and pretty close to what I want. Can you add that to the answer here? Btw. I stand corrected: it makes a difference whether returning the class definition or a class expression. At least in the playground (probably due to a newer TS version, compared to mine).

Comment: @MikeLischke I updated the answer and yeah, TS prob got smarter from your version.